# Scala IDE Call Spark But Executor Not Start

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, scala-ide

I have Scala IDE Problem. The code below

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("xxx").setMaster("local[*]")
```

running in Scala IDE works fine, But

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("xxx").setMaster("spark://ipOfMyPC:7077")
```

can't work. and error message is

**WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient memory**

I have checked with Spark-Shell, Spark-Shell Web UI use port 4040 and work fine. That's the reason I found Executor did not start.

Scala IDE service SparkUI use port 4041 automatically and I found Executor did not start, only driver exists. I have tried this code below, but not work

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("xxx").set("spark.executor.instances", "2").set("spark.executor.memory", "1g").setMaster("spark://ipOfMyPC:7077")
```

How to solve this issue in Scala IDE?

My Platform is windows 8.1 and firewall is disabled.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although Scala IDE service SparkUI use port 4041 instead 4040 automatically.
After Stop Spark-Shell(on port 4040), The Scala IDE job can run successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Go to spark UI : `yourip:8080`

find the link of master url like :  `spark://xyz:7077`

use this as master url.

use `start-all.sh` command to start all nodes.